# Binding image in listview just displaying string

Tags: c#, image, listview, binding

What's wrong with this picture?

[image]

Instead of displaying a nice picture of a prehistoric plant, the string of the location of the bitmap is being displayed!

Here's the XAML (snippet):

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="YoungPicCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="200" Width="200" Stretch="None"  Source="{Binding Path=YoungPicBmp}"    />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The filenames (and other data) are loaded at runtime from an XML file.

Here is the data being loaded from the XML file at runtime:

```
    public class LVData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string YoungPic { get; set; }
        public BitmapSource YoungPicBmp { get { return new BitmapImage(new Uri("{YoungPic}")); } }
        public string MediumPic { get; set; }
        public BitmapSource MediumPicBmp { get { return new BitmapImage(new Uri("{MediumPic}")); } }
        public string AdultPic { get; set; }
        public BitmapSource AdultPicBmp { get { return new BitmapImage(new Uri("{AdultPic}")); } }
        public bool SaltWater { get; set; }
        public bool FreshWater { get; set; }
        public bool Grasslands { get; set; }
        public bool Swamp { get; set; }
        public bool TropicalForest { get; set; }
        public bool Forest { get; set; }
        public bool ForestEdge { get; set; }
        public bool Sand { get; set; }
        public bool Coastal { get; set; }
        public bool RiverBorder { get; set; }
        public bool LakeBorder { get; set; }
        public bool Floodplain { get; set; }
    }


    public class WindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        //called when a property is changed
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
                
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<LVData> _plantList = new ObservableCollection<LVData>();
        public ObservableCollection<LVData> lsvData
        {
            get { return _plantList; }
            set { _plantList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("lsvData"); }
        }

        public void PopulateDataFromXML(string filename)
        {
            XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"DinoIslandPlants.xml");


            var Plants = from x in loaded.Descendants("Plants")
                          select new
                          {
                              Name = x.Descendants("Name").First().Value,
                              YoungPic = x.Descendants("YoungPic").First().Value,
                              MediumPic = x.Descendants("MediumPic").First().Value,
                              AdultPic = x.Descendants("AdultPic").First().Value,
                              SaltWater = x.Descendants("SaltWater").First().Value,
                              FreshWater = x.Descendants("FreshWater").First().Value, 
                              Grasslands = x.Descendants("Grasslands").First().Value, 
                              Swamp = x.Descendants("Swamp").First().Value, 
                              TropicalForest = x.Descendants("TropicalForest").First().Value, 
                              Forest = x.Descendants("Forest").First().Value, 
                              ForestEdge = x.Descendants("ForestEdge").First().Value, 
                              Sand = x.Descendants("Sand").First().Value, 
                              Coastal = x.Descendants("Coastal").First().Value,
                              RiverBorder = x.Descendants("RiverBorder").First().Value,
                              LakeBorder = x.Descendants("LakeBorder").First().Value,
                              Floodplain = x.Descendants("Floodplain").First().Value
                          };
            foreach (var _plant in Plants)
            {
                _plantList.Add(new LVData { 
                    Name = _plant.Name,
                    YoungPic = _plant.YoungPic, 
                    MediumPic = _plant.MediumPic, 
                    AdultPic = _plant.AdultPic, 
                    SaltWater = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.SaltWater),
                    FreshWater = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.FreshWater),
                    Grasslands = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.Grasslands),
                    Swamp = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.Swamp),
                    TropicalForest = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.TropicalForest),
                    Forest = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.Forest),
                    Sand = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.Sand),
                    Coastal = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.Coastal),
                    RiverBorder = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.RiverBorder),
                    LakeBorder = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.LakeBorder),
                    Floodplain = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.Floodplain) 
                     
                });

            }

            RaisePropertyChanged("lsvData");
            
        }
     
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of `YoungPic`?

Comment: It's a string; just added code above.

Comment: Here's a link to the entire listview that shows complete path strings, etc.: http://www.dowce.com/~J8p

Answer (score 1):

When binding to an `Image` control you need to bind to a `BitmapSource`. This should be pretty straight forward. Change the type of the property **(or add a new one)** to `BitmapSource` and then in the `get` do something like this:

```
... get { return new BitmapImage(new Uri("{PathToImage}")); }
```

where `PathToImage` is a recognizable path to the image you want to display.

Comment: First, thanks very much... I never ever heard of a BitmapSource! Anyway, it's throwing this error when I modify the above class: must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial (it's complaining about the 'set')

Comment: @zetar: oh, since the `get` now has a body, you need to actually do something with the `set`. I'm guessing you probably need to declare a `private` field **or** get rid of it all together.

Comment: If I eliminate set it throws an error (YoungPic cannot be assigned to -- it is read only... here:                         YoungPic = _plant.YoungPic,

Comment: @zetar, I think you're going to have to create a new property (like I suggested might have to be done). Put the old property back to `get; set;` and then build a new property that's just a `get` and returns the `BitmapSource`. When sending in the path to the `Uri` use the current property `YoungPic` to get that value.

Comment: I've updated the XAML and code (above) to reflect these changes... still, unfortunately, just displaying the paths. What am I doing wrong?